# Is an antiderivative a "$-1^{\text{th}}$" derivative?

Tags: calculus

Could you rewrite $\int\left[ f\left(x\right) \right]dx$ as $\frac{d^{-1}}{dx^{-1}}[f(x)]$, and, in turn, $f^{(-1)}(x)$? Are they the same thing?

Think about it. Subtraction is adding a negative, multiplication and exponentiation are division and roots (respectively) by a reciprocal, it would just make sense to be able to define integration in terms of differentiation.

Comment: To the person who downvoted, could you please tell me how to improve this question? Anonymous downvotes are no help at all, but the constructive criticism could really help me out! :)

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that the antiderivative is only defined up to a constant. You’d need to fix a point $a$ beforehand to define $f^{(-1)}(x)=\int_a^xf(x)\,dx$.

Comment: You could just take f^{(-1}) to be some expression plus an integration constant, just like an ordinary indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly; informally, yes. Let's think about it with $f(x)=\ln x$:
\begin{align}f^{(1)}(x)&=\frac1x\\f^{(2)}(x)&=-\frac1{x^2}\\f^{(3)}(x)&=\frac2{x^3}\\&\,\,\vdots\end{align}
If going down this column means adding $1$ to the differential order, then going up must mean subtracting $1$ from the differential order. So, if you will, $f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)=\ln x$ and, extrapolating more, $f^{(-1)}(x)=\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\text{dx}$.

**Notation-relating stuff.** This is rather intuitive, but it conflicts with the existing notation that is widely used for an inverse function, $f^{-1}(x)$, which you *could* fix with the parentheses, but it is striking the existing notation, which has been since centuries, and people who read your work might not acknowledge a $-1^{\text{th}}$ derivative.

You could think of this way, but I would only do so if I were trying to remember, which I don't really see a reason in doing. The only practical use would be in notation, but you would be born $400$ years too late.

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly answers my question! (FYI, there are so many practical changes I'd like to make to mathematical notation that I'm 400 years late to make)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suppose $f^{(-1)}(x)$ does mean the first antiderivative of $x$ (you are *technically* correct), although the integral notation is so much more common that no one else would decide to write $f^{(-1)}(x)$.

I *have* seen Euler notation, that is, $D_{x}^{-1}f(x)$, to represent the antiderivative, but never LaGrange notation $f^{(-1)}(x)$.

If you were seeking to use unorthodox notation, you could use [Newton's Notation for Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton%27s_notation_for_integration).

And of course, if $f^{(-1)}(x)$ represents the antiderivative, that would mean that $f^{(-1)}(x) \neq f^{-1}(x)$, which is an interesting statement to write.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-When I was a fifteen-year-old teenager, when studying the derivatives of order $n$ of a function $f(x)$, I observed that if a closed form could be obtained for said derivative as a function of $n$ then in some cases by setting $n=-1$ the integral of $f(x)$ could be obtained. However this form was not always applicable.

It works for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=xe^{-x}$ and other cases because
$$f^{(n)}(\sin(x))=\sin\left(x+\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)\\f^{(n)}(xe^{-x})=(-1)^nxe^{-x}-(-1)^{n+1}ne^{-x}$$ but it does not work for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$  and $f(x)=\dfrac1x$ because
$$f^{(n)}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}\\f^{(n)}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{x^{1+n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is used in [fractional calculus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalCalculus.html) for [fractional integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalIntegral.html), [fractional derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) and [differintegral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral).